# Trying to show all numbers lower than the average in another list

Tags: python, list, random, iteration, average

For school we have to make a code which shows the average of a certain list into another list but for some reason my list which should show the smaller numbers is empty, I don't know if it is possible but I tried using an extra variable which counts +1 to itself

```
from random import randint

kleiner = []
list = []
teller = 0
aantal = int(input("Hoeveel random getallen wilt u? "))
veelvoud = int(input("Welke veelvoud? "))

while len(list) < aantal:
    getal = randint(1, 100)
    if getal % veelvoud == 0:
        list.append(getal)
gemiddelde = sum(list) / len(list)

while len(list) < aantal:
    if list[teller] < gemiddelde:
        kleiner.append(list[teller])
        teller += 1

print(list)
print(list[::-1])
print(kleiner)
```

help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to see when you *expected* it to add to this list, but did not?  That would help explain *why* it doesn't.

Comment: Please **NEVER** use `list` as the name for a list, it's a builtin function.

Comment: "list" is a type, not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

- don't name a variable `list` as `list` is also a python type
- the second `while` loop causes the issue, as the length of the list is by default equal to `aantal` as the list has already been created. So whatever is in the while loop is never executed. Rather you could just iterate over the list in a simple for loop

That makes:

```
from random import randint

kleiner = []
list_ = []
teller = 0
aantal = int(input("Hoeveel random getallen wilt u? "))
veelvoud = int(input("Welke veelvoud? "))

while len(list_) < aantal:
    getal = randint(1, 100)
    if getal % veelvoud == 0:
        list_.append(getal)
gemiddelde = sum(list_) / len(list_)

for i in list_:
    if i < gemiddelde:
        kleiner.append(i)

print(list_)
print(list_[::-1])
print(kleiner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the average (gemiddelde), you can build the resulting list using a list comprehension:

```
kleiner = [n for n in list_ if n < gemiddelde ]
```

If you want a list of random numbers that are a multiple of veelvoud <= 100, you can get that using the choices() function:

```
list_ = random.choices(range(velvoud,100,velvoud), k=aantal)
```